# Laravel: Prevent Sql injection Wild Card or Like Clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to ask 
,how can i prevent SQL Injection to the script of **wild card or Like Clause**

This is my script

```
$user_location = DB::table('store_locator')
->Where('city','like','%' . $inpaddress . '%')
->orWhere('store_address','like','%' . $inpaddress . '%')
->get();
```

Is it okay to use like this one?

'%' . $inpaddress . '%'

Thanks. I hope you will suggest what is better. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Laravel by default prevents the sql injection very well. If you are still in doubt and your PDO configs are some how messed up you can try.

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options'   => [
                \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
            ]
        ],
```

Set `\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` it will

```
'options'   => [
                    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
                ]
```

Comment: so laravel prevent already the sql injection? i see. thanks adnan